# How do i import MySQLdb module on GAE?

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine

Am building an intranet site and am using GAE, but i want to access some data that lies in some MYSQl database.

How do i import MySQLdb module?

When i try:

```
import MySQLdb
```

GAE complains that there is no module named MySQLdb!!

When is try this;

```
import django.db.backends.mysql
```

it goes through,seems like GAE likes django (parasitic behavior).

I need to use MySQLdb module and MySQLdb.cursors

Help

Comment: Can you clarify this more. GAE does not have a mysql database the only SQL-type access is via Google App Engine for Business which I think is in an invite only stage. Do you mean you want to do some work on porting some data while working locally or are you really trying to use MySQL on AppEngine (which is not possible)

Answer (score 5):

- There is no MySQL infrastructure on GAE
- Connecting to an external MySQL data source would imply working outside of [the sandbox](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#The_Sandbox)
- Using mysql during local development might be possible, but ultimately pointless.

If you need to access an external data source, you will need to do so over some kind of HTTP API using [urlfetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/)